# file upload in JSF using myfaces component

Tags: jsf

I am creating a JSF application where file uploading functionality is required.I have added all the required jar files in my /WEB-INF/lib folder.

```
jsf-api.jar
jsf-impl.jar
jstl.jar
standard.jar
myfaces-extensions.jar
commons-collections.jar
commons-digester.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-logging.jar
commons-fileupload-1.0.jar
```

but still when trying to deploy the application on apache 6.0.29 i am getting the following error.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already
configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/jsfApplication] startup failed due to previous errors
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesJdbc
 The web application [/jsfApplication] registered the JBDC driver
[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web
application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been
forcibly unregistered.
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/jsfApplication] appears to have started a thread
named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a
memory leak.
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/jsfApplication] appears to have started a thread
named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This
is very likely to create a memory leak.
log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in
class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
```

i am using also using hibernate and spring framework for this application.

please help.

thanks,

#### Update:

This is the complete error message which I am getting whenever I am adding myFaces-extension.jar file to my /WEB-INF/lib folder.

```
Using CATALINA_BASE: /home/prt/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.29 Using CATALINA_HOME: /home/prt/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.29 Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/prt/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/temp Using JRE_HOME: /usr/jdk1.6.0_20 Using CLASSPATH: /home/prt/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/bin/bootstrap.jar 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/jdk1.6.0_20/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/jdk1.6.0_20/jre/lib/i386:/usr/jdk1.6.0_20/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:54 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization processed in 643 ms 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start INFO: Starting service Catalina 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR INFO: Deploying web application archive jsfApplication.war 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:55 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile INFO: validateJarFile(/home/prt/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/jsfApplication/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener INFO: The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored. 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start SEVERE: Error listenerStart 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start SEVERE: Context [/jsfApplication] startup failed due to previous errors 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc SEVERE: The web application [/jsfApplication] registered the JBDC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered. 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [/jsfApplication] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [/jsfApplication] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository. 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying web application directory examples 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load java.net.BindException. The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact. java.lang.IllegalStateException at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1531) at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491) at com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException.(CommunicationsException.java:161) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2759) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.quit(MysqlIO.java:1410) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.realClose(Connection.java:4947) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.cleanup(Connection.java:2063) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.finalize(Connection.java:3403) at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Native Method) at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:83) at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:14) at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:160) 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying web application directory docs 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:58 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:58 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:58 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/24 config=null 8 Jan, 2011 7:08:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in 3905 ms
```

Comment: Please post the part which `previous errors` is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I got also problems with myfaces-extensions using x tags. The conflict is due to the fact that myfaces is a very old solution and if your other libraries are uptodate the versions won't match. As posted at [tomahawk inputfileupload uploaded file is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600421/tomahawk-inputfileupload-uplodaed-file-is-null) in my answer you should use tomahawk t tag and libraries related to it. Actual solution is posted in the main answer of that very same link.

I'm pretty sure this will do the thing. Tick my answer if the post included the answer to your question in its wiki-link :)